# methods are not executed in android studio

Tags: android

```
06-15 14:51:25.685 22821-22821/com.example.sajols.basketballscore E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475) 
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1068)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4546)
                                                                                        at com.example.sajols.basketballscore.MainActivity.displayScoreTeamB(MainActivity.java:73)
                                                                                        at com.example.sajols.basketballscore.MainActivity.twoPointsTeamB(MainActivity.java:62)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475) 
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `String resource ID #0x2 at ` means passing `int` to setText method

Comment: I quickly edited with formatting the error cause it hurt my eyes. what you need to do is add some code and add some bloody sentences in English explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are trying to call onClick method from XML. Kindly share the code